# How to download a aar file from a private gitlab repo via gradle

Tags: android, gradle, ant, gitlab, aar

I am trying to download a dependancy library `mylibrary.aar` from my `gitlab` repository via `gradle`. I understand that we dont have any closures/methods in gradle to directly get files from a `http` url.

Therefore am using `ant`'s getmethod to download the library from `gitlab`.

Here is the code am using in my `gradle` file to get the library.

```
task downloadlib {

ant.get(src: 'https://my-git-link/mylibrary.aar', dest: 'libs', verbose: 'on')

}

dependencies {

compile(name: 'mylibrary', ext: 'aar')

}
```

**Problem :**

The files which I download via the ant's get method seems to be corrupted/does not go through the download process properly. Not sure what goes wrong. The library does not get compiled and the dependencies cannot be resolved. When I try to extract the `aar` it again extracts to `cgpz` file in my mac.I havent tried in windows though.

However, if I manually download the same `aar` file and reference it in the libs folder it works absolutely fine.

1. Any idea why does this happen?
2. Is there any other way to download a `aar` file from a gitlab server apart from `ant.get`?

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Note : I cannot use a locally built dependancy as all my libraries are on different repo and the project requirement mandates the same.Also, the code cannot be posted in github and thats the reason I did not choose `jitpack`

The same problem occurs for `jar` files as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to declare git repository as dependency in android gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748436/is-it-possible-to-declare-git-repository-as-dependency-in-android-gradle)

Comment: @BertrandMartel Appreciate your help. The answer provided in the other question is for people who have their code publicly in github. In my case the code cannot be shared. I have posted a solution. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think I have a direct solution for the problem as `gradle` does not have an api for this. Instead what I did was, created my own maven repository using `jfrog`'s `artifactory` and hosted the libraries there so that all the developers can refer to the libraries from the internal artifactory.

The artifactory OSS version can be downloaded from [here](https://jfrog.com/open-source/)

I chose `artifactory` because it was much simpler and had a great UI. Most of all it did not require setting up a separate `github` repository for this purpose as the code cannot be shared outside the organization.

After setting up, your libraries can be accessed as below.

http://localhost:8081/artifactory.

A brief description of setting up an artifactory is provided [here](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2015/08/06/artifactory/)

After the libraries are hosted in your `artifactory` which can be located anywhere in your network, u or any other developer in your organization may access your libraries using the maven dependency manager in android.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this example:

```
implementation 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:2.5.2@aar'
implementation('com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.5.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
    }
```

Comment: This will work only if the library is hosted in `jcenter` or atleast a local `maven` repository. Thats not my question. My question is how do you get  a library from a gitlab repo.