# How to use java files from git repo as dependency in gradle

Tags: java, git, gradle

### Problem:

I'm writting a gui for visualization based on a framework that is stored as a git repository. That git directory only contains the source files, no 'build.gradle' file. The JavaFX application I'm developing, should use gradle to controll the dependencies. 
The framework should become a submodule of the new git repository for the gui.
The framework and the gui have the same root package 'com.ACME.fancySolution'

### I've tried:

I know how to import subproject, that contain a gradle build file but that's not the right solution here.

I have already tried to change the source set, with no effect

### Requeriments:

The framework is submodule -> no redudant code/files
Building with gradle
If possible no changes on the existing framework repository

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748436/is-it-possible-to-declare-git-repository-as-dependency-in-android-gradle

Comment: JitPack is only for github if I understand it correctly
But my git server is a local TFS
The second solution refers to gradle subprojects