# Android module dependency from private bitbucket repository

Tags: android, gradle, bitbucket

I have a Bitbucket android project (private), with multiple modules as below:

```
my_android_project
-> module_1
-> module_2
-> module_3
```

Its possible to use the modules, as gradle dependency, like this? (i'd like to use this modules in multiple projects)

```
implementation 'com.package.my_android_project:module_1:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.package.my_android_project:module_2:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.package.my_android_project:module_3:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to declare git repository as dependency in android gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748436/is-it-possible-to-declare-git-repository-as-dependency-in-android-gradle)

Comment: This link shows how to do this with a GitHub repo. I suggest looking at the link to JitPack to see if it support BitBucket.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. I'm using bitbucket. JitPack does not have a free plan to support private repos

Comment: @ViníciusCarvalho Have you found the solution finally?