# 'Fork' git repository as dependency in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, jitpack

I made a topic some hours ago that lead me to a public repository : https://github.com/biezhi/webp-io

However, I had to update the library used, cwebp and make changes to the code.
Its my first fork.

My fork is located here: https://github.com/KenobySky/webp-io

```
maven {url "https://jitpack.io"}
...
compile 'com.github.KenobySky:webp-io:master'
```

---

**Question:**
Im trying to declare this 'fork' git repository as dependency in gradle but I get this error below, what should I do ?

---

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
  > Could not find com.github.KenobySky:webp-io:master.
    Searched in the following locations:
      - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/KenobySky/webp-io/master/webp-io-master.pom
    If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
    Required by:
        project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

**References**

[Is it possible to declare git repository as dependency in android gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748436/is-it-possible-to-declare-git-repository-as-dependency-in-android-gradle)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

• Make sure to add `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` inside `allprojects` in `build.gradle` **project** file as

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        // Note: Add this here
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

• Now add the dependency in `build.gradle` **app**  as

```
android {...}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    // ....
    implementation 'com.github.KenobySky:webp-io:master'
}
```

It works!

Alternately, You can use

```
implementation 'com.github.KenobySky:webp-io:0.06'
```

There is a typo in your release tag and release tag title, tag has `v0.06` value but the title has `v0.0.6`

[image]

You can delete this release tag and create a new one with `v0.0.6` or better to use `0.0.6` as a convention.