# How to add the code in a private GitHub repository as a Gradle dependency?

Tags: gradle

I have tried using all the given methods, but no luck. Please help.

I have tried using Jitpack, but it is paid for Private repositories.

I also used Source Control, but it does not have Authentication implemented.

Comment: [See comments under this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56787382/9546874) linking to the following: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/limitations-of-gradle-source-dependencies/28956/20. Might be of help