# Could not resolve git repository as dependency in android gradle

Tags: android, gradle, git-submodules, gradle-kotlin-dsl, jitpack

I am trying to add a git repository (https://github.com/FHNW-IP5-IP6/ComposeForms) as a dependency into my project with Gradle and tried the below-listed variants (1.-3.) from [Is it possible to declare git repository as dependency in android gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748436/is-it-possible-to-declare-git-repository-as-dependency-in-android-gradle) but every time when I sync the project I get an Error saying: **"Could not resolve com.github.FHNW-IP5-IP6:ComposeForms:master-SNAPSHOT"**.

I tried the following:

1. Jitpack (https://jitpack.io/#FHNW-IP5-IP6/ComposeForms/master-SNAPSHOT)

   ```
   allprojects {
     repositories {
       ...
       maven("https://jitpack.io") // also tried uri https://www.jitpack.io
     }
   }
   ```

   and in app build.gradle

   ```
   kotlin {
     sourceSets {
       named("main") {
         dependencies {
           ...
           implementation("com.github.FHNW-IP5-IP6:ComposeForms:master-SNAPSHOT")
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Git Submodule (named as compose-forms)

   `include(":compose-forms")` inside settings.gradle

   ```
   kotlin {
     sourceSets {
       named("main") {
         dependencies {
           ...
           implementation(project(":compose-forms"))
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. New feature in gradle

   Inside settings.gradle

   ```
   sourceControl {
     gitRepository(uri("https://github.com/FHNW-IP5-IP6/ComposeForms.git")) {
       producesModule("compose-forms")
     }
   }
   ```

   and in app build.gradle

   ```
   kotlin {
     sourceSets {
       named("main") {
         dependencies {
           ...
           implementation("compose-forms") {
             version {
               branch = "master"
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

I'm running out of options and really need the git repository as a dependency. I would prefer not to have any git submodules inside my project so I prefer numbers 1 and 3 to work. Thanks in Advance for any hint :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Android Studio as Administrator then add **maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }** to both, **build.gradle(project)** and **settings.gradle(project)** and the respective **implementation [...]** to **build.gradle(:app)**. This worked for me as every other solution proposed failed.

Comment: Man you deserve a salute!! Thanks a lot.