# Early access to Github libraries before official release

Tags: github, kotlin-exposed, github-release

I am using the JetBrains Exposed library available [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) on Github.

The latest release was in November 2022 however, since then, there have been merged pull requests which have added additional api functionality.

At the moment my Gradle dependency is using version `0.41.1` (the November 2022 release). Is there any way to get access to the latest (pre-release) version of the library for use in my application?

### Current Dependencies

```kotlin
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-core:0.41.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-dao:0.41.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-jdbc:0.41.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-java-time:0.41.1")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to declare git repository as dependency in android gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748436/is-it-possible-to-declare-git-repository-as-dependency-in-android-gradle)

Comment: looks promising, will take a look

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with jitpack.io.
Please check the related [FAQ section](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/FAQ#q-where-can-i-find-snapshot-builds-of-exposed)

Comment: Do I need to include multiple lines for each dependency e.g. core, dao, jdbc , java-time? The faq only inlcudes one line `implementation 'com.github.JetBrains:Exposed:-SNAPSHOT'. An example with the latest snapshot would be much appreciated.